# Why does a text file written by file_put_contents write double lines?

Tags: php

Good morning, friends.  I've struggled and googled and I can't seem to find an answer.  If it's been answered on here already and I missed it, please feel free to direct me to what I missed.

I have the following bit of PHP code.  It works fine when I run it on my Mac (and the non-Windows machines of some friends), but when I run it on Windows (where it's going to live here at work), it writes each line to the text file twice.  PHP here at work is 5.3.6 running on IIS 6.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

$fltSupervision = trim(htmlentities($_POST["txtSupervision"]));
$fltDrugTestUA = trim(htmlentities($_POST["txtDrugTestUA"]));
$fltAlcoholSensor = trim(htmlentities($_POST["txtAlcoholSensor"]));
$fltTotal = trim(htmlentities($_POST["txtTotal"]));
$fltSurcharge = trim(htmlentities($_POST["txtSurcharge"]));

$strTransaction = $fltSupervision . "\t" . $fltDrugTestUA . "\t" . $fltAlcoholSensor . "\t" . $fltSurcharge . "\t" . $fltTotal . PHP_EOL;
echo $strTransaction;

$file = 'fees.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $strTransaction, FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

Jeremy

Comment: I tested your code on my server and it checks out. There is something else causing this, maybe your form itself. If you reload the page twice, then yes it will save it twice, because of `FILE_APPEND` - reload the page 3 times and the file will have 3 entries. Did you maybe hit the submit button twice by accident maybe? Just checking out the possibilities. If you don't want it to append, then take out `, FILE_APPEND`

Comment: as suggested by @Fred-ii- if you check for what requests are received either there will probably be 2 requests, or one request that calls this chunk of code twice.

Comment: @AD7six I think the OP may have stepped out to get himself a Latté with a shot of Espresso. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, guys!  I had a meeting about something way less fun than PHP!  As a test, I made another little script where I set the values myself without needing to use an HTML page to make a request.  See it on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EfPesbwx).  It does the same thing: one line per write on OS X, two per write on Windows.

Comment: The test doesn't show anything of relevance.

Comment: It showed me that I had the same results without a post from a web form.

Comment: Guys, I've done more testing and it only appears to happen when I call the PHP running on the Windows server from a browser running INSIDE our network at work. Now that I've been able to do tests at home, I see that the double lines don't happen from here. So, weird networking issue? If no one has a great and cool explanation, I guess I'll make that the answer here.

Answer (score 5):

It probably has something to do with a missing favicon.ico.

Try changing .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And try creating a favicon.ico file by creating an empty .txt file renaming it to favicon.ico.

Many browsers look for a favicon.ico file and if that file doesn't exist and your .htaccess file is setup to direct to your script, the script will be executed twice and the text will be added twice to fees.txt.

Comment: How do you expect adding/changing rewrite rules (`running on IIS 6.` :?) to solve the problem? Note also that the code relies on post data, requests for a missing favicon.ico are not going to have any post data.

Comment: I missed the part saying IIS 6. But I'm pretty sure it's a missing favicon.ico file that is causing the script to be executed twice. Another solution would be to add a real favicon.ico file. Then the browsers request on favicon.ico will not be redirected.

Comment: Hey there!  I've added the favicon tag to the HTML page that calls this PHP code and that hasn't made a difference.  Maybe I should have also mentioned that the behavior is the same if I skip the post data and hard-code my own test values for those variables.

Comment: @mrcoulson Have you tried running the script through command line? If this does not give the same result, the problem is not the script but the browser.

Comment: Good call. I'll try that!

Comment: @CasperAndréCasse I tried my no-form-needed version of the script ([http://pastebin.com/EfPesbwx](http://pastebin.com/EfPesbwx)) from the command line on the Windows server and I only get one line of output instead of two.  After more testing, it seems that Windows browsers running the script from a Windows server cause the double lines.  OS X browsers running the script from the Windows server do not.  Now it's even less clear than before.

Comment: @mrcoulson You could try to log `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to a file to see exactly which URL's are requested. That file should end up containing 2 URL's, and one of these is the one causing the double execution.

Comment: it is really interesting that htaccess cosing this happen, but good catch. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can only possible if you are refreshing your page. Your current code will append your contents in fees.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the PHP_EOL may be the thing that is throwing your text editor.  If the PHP_EOL is defined as "\r\n" this could produce a space between lines in your text file.

Try and set your own end of line character to just "\n" and see if this fixes it.

```
$strTransaction = $fltSupervision . "\t" . $fltDrugTestUA . "\t" . $fltAlcoholSensor . "\t" . $fltSurcharge . "\t" . $fltTotal . "\n";
```

Comment: Hello!  Actually, I had `\n` when I first started to have this problem and a friend suggested I change it to `PHP_EOL` as an attempt to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my server and it checks out. There may something else causing this (if that is the case), maybe your form itself. If you reload the page twice, then yes it will save it twice, because of `FILE_APPEND`

Did you maybe hit the submit button twice by accident maybe? Just checking out the possibilities. If you don't want it to append, then take out `, FILE_APPEND`

Answer (score 0):

The answer ends up being pretty weird.  After lots of testing, I discovered that it only happens when I use a Windows machine at work to load the script from a Windows server at work.  If the client machine is not on our corporate network, it behaves as expected.  Since weird network behavior is probably far outside the scope of the original post, let's take that as the answer.  I began to understand this when I followed Casper's advice and ran the script from command line on my Windows server.

Thanks, everyone for giving me ideas and helping me learn a little more.  Have a great day.